# Finding source query in execution plan of nested views and UDFs

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a view containing N levels of nested views with UDFs and TVFs that I have to tune and my execution plan has 630+ nodes.

I found the performance issue in the plan but I can't find the source query from within all the nested views. Is there an easy way to find the culprit query or am I doomed to dig through it all and test each query out?

The database is an Azure SQL Instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### unfortunate

There's not an easy way to do that, because views are inlined like any query abstraction. Probably the least painful way is to use the "View Dependencies" tab in SSMS to find which views depend on which functions.

[image: NUTS]

For example, the dependency report for Ola's scripts show the objects that depend on `dbo.CommandExecute`.

[image: NUTS]

Comment: Well, at least that saves me some time in just annoyingly digging into the views. Thanks Erik! This way I can also determine the N levels of hierarchy in my views. Fortunately, it's just only 10 levels.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu It could always be worse 